# CefSharp web browser with Zscaler and F5 doesn't cache SSO credentials

Tags: caching, single-sign-on, cefsharp, f5, zscaler

A customer has ZScaler and F5's.

This causes a problem each time [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample) is run as ZScaler kicks in, eg: https://gateway.zscalerthree.net/ and redirects to a page https://XYZ.com.au/ntlm/auth that results in a AuthenticationFailure:

[image]

Users have to set the web address to F5's BIP-IP login page, eg:
https://XYZ.com.au/my.policy

[image]

This doesn't happen in Google Chrome, how can I cache the credentials or avoid users having to login each time?

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1150/ntlm-authentication-issue

Comment: hi, which part? i have seen your other posts here and did research that link before (sorry for not stating) but it didnt help. An answer would be great, the current cef build doesnt work (connection timeout) so i'm at a loss and dont want to spend hours more on this.

Comment: let me try the patch, how do you add to the whitelists?

Comment: You are using a build from the `2785` branch as you can see from the screen shot above, those changes were applied to the `2840` and newer, hence you'd need to upgrade. You'd have to manually upgrade to a newer version of `CEF` as there is currently no `CefSharp` build that references a `CEF` version that includes the relevant changes. Before you ask about the next `CefSharp` release you should read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1841

Comment: thxs @amaitland